# Inducing Opportunity Attacks in conjunction with War Caster feat

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack

Let's consider a multiclassed Tempest Cleric with some levels in Storm Sorcerer (from *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*). That character also has the War Caster feat, which states

> When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

Storm Sorcerer gives the character access to [Gust](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gust), which can induce the following effect:

> One Medium or smaller creature that you choose must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed up to 5 feet away from you.

After using their Action to cast Gust on their turn and pushing a hostile creature 5 ft away, can this character use their Reaction to cast a cantrip such as [Shocking Grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp) or a suitable spell that targets a single creature, as stated by the War Caster feat?

Asked more generally: can I use movement **induced by myself** to trigger an Opportunity Attack?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: I tried finding a similar question but did not find the one you linked. That one does, however, answer my question perfectly.